# How do I make a for loop that checks for every int

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Okay, this is really hard to explain.
I basically have one integer that is called box and I need to check if the person has one box and then add one box as an item and so on.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this or how do I do this?

For example: If the integer is equal to three I need to check for one box and add an item and then check for another and add an item. I've thought about adding a for loop or something, I do not have any idea of what to do right now as I'm stuck with this.

I have not tried anything yet as I dont know how to fix this.

```java
public static void openMysteryBox(Player p) {
    Inventory mysterybox = Bukkit.createInventory(p, 9, "Mystery Boxes");

    ItemStack hasMysteryBox = new ItemBuilder(Material.ENDER_CHEST, 1)
        .setName("§eMysteryBox")
        .setLore("§7Right click to open this mysterybox!")
        .toItemStack();

    int boxes = plugin.getMysteryboxes();
    if(boxes >= 1) {
         // I want to check for every 1 boxes.
    }
}
```

There are no error messages but I dont really know what to do at this point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! I'm having a really hard time understanding your question, especially because I see no link between your question and your code. I'd suggest you take basic tutorials on computer programming, and get familiar with it until you're confident enough to explain your problem clearly. Good luck and keep on !

Comment: Okay so I have something called "boxes" as I explained above. Those boxes are integer that are stored in a setter and getter file that I have. There's something called an inventory in minecraft. I want to make it so the amount of "boxes" that a player has should be displayed in the inventory. To be able to achive that I need to make a box itemstack and to avoid making 100 of those itemstacks I need to have something that makes a itemstack every 1 box that the player has.

Comment: So for example if a player has 1 box 1 box is displayed in the inventory by using the itemstack or if a player has 3 boxes 3 are displayed in the inventory

Comment: This is really hard to explain as 99% of the people here do not know Bukkit api or minecraft at all so its really hard to explain.

Comment: Even me, someone who has made multiple mods using Forge *could not understand your question.* Your comment is actually more clear than the entirety of your question. All you had to ask was, "how can I count how many of a specific item the player has in their inventory?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Forge but not Bukkit, so feel free to modify as needed.

Assuming that...

Inventory has methods:

- `getSlot(int index)` returning the slot at index, first slot at 0;

Slot has methods:

- `setStack(ItemStack stack)` setting this slot's ItemStack to the supplied stack

And a Copier:

- `static <T> T copyOf(T object)` returning a new object that satisfies `Copier.copyOf(object).equals(object)`

```java
ItemStack box =
new ItemBuilder(Material.ENDER_CHEST)
.setName("Mystery Box")
.setLore("Rightclick to open this box");
.toItemStack();

if (boxes > 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < boxes; i++)
  {
    boxInventory.getSlot(i).setStack(Copier.copy(box));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me out!

Answer (score 2):

Just stabbing in the dark here: are you looking for something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < boxes; i++) {
     //Check box, add item
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I'm not sure if a for loop will work. I've thought about it. I'll try though, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did think of doing a loop but I didn't think that it would work, thanks!